# Send a signal to an app engine module in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How can I send a request to another app engine module without waiting for their response?

I want to start a background process from another module. As they explain in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Communication_between_modules), you can communicate between modules using `file_get_contents` or the URL Fetch service, but the background process will take longer and the original request will be timed out before the response arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the task queue.

You can set up a named push queue to point at a specific module then create tasks with a 0 second delay.

This effectively acts as an asynchronous HTTP call to the other module.

Learn more here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/